# How to use Amazon Rekognition in Unity3D?

Tags: amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, sdk, amazon-rekognition

I’ve faced such a problem:

In the documentations AWS have Rekognition SDK of Unity3D https://aws.amazon.com/ru/documentation/sdk-for-unity/

By downloading AWS Mobile SDK for Unity3D the Rekognition Amazon is absent, although it contains some other different sdks (S3, Lambda and others).

Through the nuget I can’t get SDK in Unity3D, because it’s in conflict with Core.

Even if I download version for the net35 directly, the conflict with Core arises which goes to SDK for Unity3D.

SDK Rekognition for Unity3D exists?

Or there is other way to connect with (refer to) Amazon Rekognition service from Unity3D?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> SDK Rekognition for Unity3D exists?

Yes, it does. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/Index.html. In the left side bar, scroll to Rekognition.

> Or there is other way to connect with (refer to) Amazon Rekognition service from Unity3D?

You can skip the SDK and directly call Rekognition via its REST API using HTTP client. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_Reference.html

Comment: If you try to to skip the SDK, generating the authorization to call the AWS REST API is quite complicated. Do not underestimate this amount of work.